# Module Not Found React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, mapping, jsx

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../components/App which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:0-36
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../components/App which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

i am getting the above error when i am trying to rum my react app. I was learning and a beginner at react js. i was learning about mapping in reactjs and when i run my app i am getting this error anyone please solve this.

the file system allocation is below.

[image: File System Syntax]

Answer (score 0):

Use `import App from "./components/App"` instead of `import App from "../components/App";`